How to combine multiple window.onscroll functions?
First function is colorful rgb scroller(next to standard scroolbar), which indicates progress of page scroll. Second one is a classic scroll to top button.
FIRST FUNCTION
HTML
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="SCROLL ME UP!">▲▲▲</button> 

JS
let mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 38 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 512) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}


function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
} 

SECOND FUNCTION
HTML
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<div id="scrollpath"></div>

JS
    let progress = document.getElementById('progressbar');
    let totalHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    window.onscroll = function () {
    let progressHeight = (window.pageYOffset / totalHeight) * 100;
    progress.style.height = progressHeight + "%";
        }

CSS

::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 0;
}
#scrollPath
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}
#progressbar
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10px;

    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff,#00ffe7);
    animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animate
{
    0%,100%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    50%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
#progressbar:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff,#00ffe7);
    filter: blur(10px);
}
#progressbar:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff,#00ffe7);
    filter: blur(30px);
}
::placeholder {
    color: white;
}

Separately functions work just fine.
It looks like that they interfere with each other.
Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?
I expect to work them simultaneously.

In what way are these functions "interfering with each other"?  Can you update this to a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem, and indicate how you're testing it and what problem you're observing?

You can only have one onscroll event as the last will overwrite the first. 
You can use window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { ... }) to append scroll events instead of overwriting them.
Another method would be to simply attach them to each other:
let mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

window.addEventListener('scroll',  function() {
  scrollFunction();
  let progressHeight = (window.pageYOffset / totalHeight) * 100;
  progress.style.height = progressHeight + "%";
};

function scrollFunction() {
  mybutton.style.display = (document.body.scrollTop > 38 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 512) ? "block" : "none";
}

Btw instead of using mybutton.style.display you could add a class to hide that element such as .d-none { display: none; }.
Then you can add the class conditionally:
mybutton.classList.toggle('d-none', (document.body.scrollTop > 38 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 512))


Sorry for late reply. Thanks for explanation, it helped a lot!
